# Event Delegation - Is it more efficient to just grab all events at a top level node?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, event-delegation

I've read that in document objects with a lot of separate event handlers scattered about it can be a lot better for performance to do event delegation at a parent node with `event.target` in it's event handler.

I was just wondering how this extends to all event handling in general. If your entire application is inside a single parent node - for example a `<div id="app"></div>` single page application, does it make sense to just grab all events at this top level node?

Would this improve performance in many instances? When would it not?

Comment: It would reduce memory usage, since you’re using fewer event listener functions, though the code complexity might increase. Performance will most likely not be significantly affected.

Comment: Event handlers are blazingly fast no matter wich element they are attached to.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a table with 10 columns and 10 rows.  If you add a handler for each cell, then you'll have 100 handlers.  If you add one handler per row, you'll have 10.  If you add a handler to the table, then you have 1.

The trade off is code complexity.  Having a handler per cell means the code is very specific as it is pertaining to a single cell and it's contents.  But at the table level, you have to isolate which cell received the event, and THEN do the same code as per the single cell.

Imagine if you had handlers to also do something when the row received the same event - now your code gets larger and more complex as you handle the different cases.

That code runs every time the event happens within the parent element, and that extra complexity can quickly get in the way.  Why go through 10 code checks to run one use case.  Triggering the event handler closer to where the event took place removes most of that additional logic.

This used to really be a problem because handlers per table cell could quickly exhaust memory on larger tables (I'm looking at you IE6).  But browsers are way better at this sort of thing now, so it becomes more a question of organizing your code for readability, understanding, maintenance, and performance..  (performance is *still* a factor though...)

Comment: Why are you looking at the dead browser? A copy-paste without attribution ..?

Comment: @Teemu - my IE6 reference was to personal experience with this sort of issue many years ago...